# Testing VueJS component containing other components written by myself

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vue-test-utils

I work on a website with multiple components that contain other components. Now I would like to test if the save button of a form is deactivated correctly if no data is set. I am using vuetify for the UI and Jest for testing.

Here is my parent component, containing the edit-user-details component:

```
    <template>
    <v-container>
        <v-form v-model="valid">
            <v-card>
                <v-card-text>
                    <edit-user-details :user="user"></edit-user-details>
                </v-card-text>
                <v-card-actions>
                    <v-btn :disabled="!valid" @click="save()">Save</v-btn>
                    <v-btn @click="cancel()">Cancel</v-btn>
                </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
        </v-form>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "edit-user",
        components: {},
        data: () => ({
            user: {},
            valid: false
        }),
        methods: {
            save() {
                ...
            },
            cancel() {
                ...}
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

This is a part of the edit-user-details component:

```
<template>
    <v-container>
        <v-text-field
                v-model="user.userName"
                label="Username*"
                required
                :rules="[v => !!v || 'Please, enter a user name.']"
        ></v-text-field>
       ...
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "edit-user-details",
        props: {
            user: {
                type: Object,
                default: () => ({})
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

And here we have my test:

```
import { mount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import EditUser from '../../src/views/EditUser'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import EditUserDetails from '../../src/components/EditUserDetails'


describe('Edited user data ', () => {

  it('can be saved if valid', () => {
      const localVue = createLocalVue();
      localVue.use(Vuetify)
      localVue.use(EditUserDetails)

      const wrapper = mount(EditUser, {
          localVue: localVue
      });

  })
})
```

The test is green because it has no assert. The main issue is, that I get this error: [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

So my question is: How can I test a component containing other components written by me?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

instead of `mount`, use `shallowMount`.

> Like mount, it creates a Wrapper that contains the mounted and
>   rendered Vue component, but with stubbed child components.

https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#shallowmount

Comment: I guess that would not help in this case because the child component contains the validation logic for each input field. The parent uses this logic to activate and deactivate the button. Stubbing the children would remove the validation logic.

Comment: cann't you mock the `Vuetify` dependency? https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#mocks

Comment: I don't need to. Vuetify works fine. It is just that I don't know how to register my own component.

Comment: basic testing rule of thumb is to dettach your tested component from its dependencies, including children components. so we should look for a way to mock them instead of supplying them to the tested parent. can you share the way you passed the data  from `edit-user-details` to `edit-user`? (events, etc)

Comment: Its a simple binding: :user="user"

Comment: you mean that `user` in  parent component gets mutated when you change its reference in the child component? in that case, you can simply add to your test, after the mounting: `wrapper.setData({ user: 'whatever' })` https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#setdata-data . hope i was any help for you.

Comment: This solution is not working. I'm still having this issue with shallowMount

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t tried this together with `createLocalVue()`, but I hope it'll help:

```js
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'

const vuetify = new Vuetify()

const wrapper = mount(Component, { ..., vuetify })
```